# How can I select mysql data with a union statement where the data matches each select statement, i.e. combine the AND operator with UNION?

Tags: php, mysql, select, union, advanced-search

Lets say I have a table with just two columns: *name* and *mood*. A row holds a persons name, and their mood, if they have multiple moods, then multiple rows are stored in the DB.

For example, in the database is John, who is happy, excited, and proud.

This is represented as

```
John Happy
John Excited
John Proud
```

What I want to do is select the name based on several moods being met. Similiar to the UNION:

```
SELECT name WHERE mood=Happy
UNION
SELECT name WHERE mood=Excited
UNION
SELECT name WHERE mood=Proud
```

However using the above union would result in:

```
John
John
John
```

Union all would result in one single result of John, but it would also select any names that only match one of the queries.

I can think of a few algorithms which would take each individual mysql_result resource (I'm using PHP), and look for matching results, but what I want to know is whether MySQL already facilitates this.

I realise the above is quite a vague generalisation, needless to say my actual program is alot more complicated and I've dumbed it down a little for this question, please don't hesitate to ask questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided you have no duplicates, you can do it with a subquery:

```
SELECT `name` FROM (
    SELECT `name`, COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `moods`
    WHERE `mood` IN ('Excited', 'Happy', 'Proud') GROUP BY `name`
) WHERE `count` = 3
```

Alternatively, you can use join:

```
SELECT `m1`.`name` FROM `moods` `m1`
JOIN `moods` `m2` USING (`name`)
JOIN `moods` `m3` USING (`name`)
WHERE `m1`.`mood` = 'Excited' AND `m2`.`mood` = 'Happy' AND `m3`.`mood` = 'Proud'
```

Not so cute, but might be faster if you use LIMIT. Or maybe not. Depends a lot on query planner.

**UPD**: thanks to Tudor Constantin for reminding me about HAVING, the first query can then be:

```
SELECT `name` FROM `moods`
WHERE `mood` IN ('Excited', 'Happy', 'Proud')
GROUP BY `name`
HAVING COUNT(*)>3
```

Comment: Thanks, I used the first one, it works quite perfectly, I've a CRON job checking for duplicates each night so no worries.

As for the update, it doesn't return any results, what difference should HAVING make?

Thanks alot.

Comment: Logic with HAVING is pretty much the same, don't know if there's any performance difference though.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, I think in this case you don't actually need a `UNION` but just multiple conditions in a `WHERE` statement.

Try this:

```
SELECT name, mood FROM myTable WHERE mood in ('Happy','Excited','Proud')
```

This *should* give the result:

```
John, Happy
John, Excited
John, Proud
```

If you don't care about getting multiple results for mood, try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name FROM myTable WHERE mood in ('Happy','Excited','Proud')
```

Which will just give:

This *should* give the result:

```
John
```

**Updated**
If you want to match ALL the conditions, you'd probably have to use subselects:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name FROM myTable 
WHERE name IN 
    (SELECT name FROM myTable WHERE mood = 'Happy')
AND name IN
    (SELECT name FROM myTable WHERE mood = 'Excited')
AND name IN
    (SELECT name FROM myTable WHERE mood = 'Proud')
```

Comment: Paul, thanks for your responce, much appreciated.

Using SELECT DISTINCT doesn't seem to bring any results, where as your first solution indeed brings all results.

Comment: Doesn't this return all the names where at least one mood matches (not all three)?

Comment: Just tried again, actually using DISTINCT brings results but they aren't matching each condition, i.e. other people who are just happy are returned. Can the AND operator be applied to your solution somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Replace UNION with INTERSECT .

Comment: there is no `INTERSECT` in MySQL

Comment: this would work (in SQL with `INTERSECT`), but seems inefficient essentially using 3 selects to achieve what *could* be done using one?

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
SELECT name FROM user_moods um1 
  INNER JOIN user_moods um2 ON um1.name = um2.name
WHERE um1.mood IN ('Happy','Excited','Proud')
GROUP BY um2.mood
HAVING COUNT(um2.mood) = 3 # the number of different moods
```

Comment: Good one, I forgot about HAVING, but why the extra join? Also, MySQL manual states that "For example, a HAVING clause must come after any GROUP BY clause and before any ORDER BY clause."

Answer (score 0):

your query is already correct. you can `ADD` an extra column using you searched word in the `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT name,'Happy' as imood WHERE mood='Happy'
  UNION
SELECT name,'Excited' as imood WHERE mood='Excited'
  UNION
SELECT name,'Proud' as imood WHERE mood='Proud'
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer, much appreciated. The problem is this returns names of people who just fulfil one of the select statements and not all of them.